# What are all the side effects of each cascade delete option for a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: core-data

Say I have two tables, **Department** and **Employee**. Each employee has exactly one department. Each department has one or more employees.

Is there any combination of cascade delete options I can use to enforce this rule without having to write special code?

In other words, here are the two rules:

1. A department can only be deleted when it has no employees.
2. When the last employee in a department gets deleted, the department should be deleted.

If not, then which set should I use in order to help me the most with enforcing this business logic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Say we have the following data in the table before each scenario is run:

```
Sales (Department)
  Amy (Employee)
  Bob (Employee)
```

---

## Scenario 1: Cascade/Nullify

```
Employee --(Cascade)--> Department
Department --(Nullify)--> Employee
```

**Delete Employee**:

Deleting Bob will cause Sales to be deleted, and Amy to have a NULL department.

```
Amy
```

**Delete Department**:

If we start over and delete Sales this time, Amy and Bob are left in the database with NULL departments.

```
Amy
Bob
```

---

## Scenario 2: Cascade/Deny

```
Employee --(Cascade)--> Department
Department --(Deny)--> Employee
```

**Delete Employee**:

Deleting Bob will raise an exception: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.)`.

**Delete Department**:

If we start over and delete Sales this time, we get the exception: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.)`.

---

## Scenario 3: Cascade/Cascade

```
Employee --(Cascade)--> Department
Department --(Cascade)--> Employee
```

**Delete Employee**:

Deleting Bob will cause Sales to be deleted. As a result, Amy gets deleted as well.

```
(empty DB)
```

**Delete Department**:

If we start over and delete Sales this time, it will cause all employes to be deleted as well.

```
(empty DB)
```

---

## Scenario 4: Nullify/Nullify

```
Employee --(Nullify)--> Department
Department --(Nullify)--> Employee
```

**Delete Employee**:

Deleting Bob will not change the rest of the database.

```
Sales
  Amy
```

Deleting Amy now will cause Sales to not have any Employees.

```
Sales
```

**Delete Department**:

If we start over and delete Sales this time, it will cause Amy and Bob to have NULL departments.

```
Amy
Bob
```

---

## Scenario 5: Nullify/Deny

```
Employee --(Nullify)--> Department
Department --(Deny)--> Employee
```

**Delete Employee**:

Deleting Bob will not change the rest of the database.

```
Sales
  Amy
```

Deleting Amy now will cause Sales to not have any Employees.

```
Sales
```

**Delete Department**:

If we start over and delete Sales this time, it will cause an exception: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.)`.

---

## Scenario 6: Nullify/Cascade

```
Employee --(Nullify)--> Department
Department --(Cascade)--> Employee
```

**Delete Employee**:

Deleting Bob will not change the rest of the database.

```
Sales
  Amy
```

Deleting Amy now will cause Sales to not have any Employees.

```
Sales
```

**Delete Department**:

If we start over and delete Sales this time, it will delete all employees.

```
(empty DB)
```

---

## Scenario 7: Deny/Nullify

```
Employee --(Deny)--> Department
Department --(Nullify)--> Employee
```

**Delete Employee**:

Deleting Bob will cause an exception: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.)`.

**Delete Department**:

If we start over and delete Sales this time, it will cause Amy and Bob to have NULL departments.

```
Amy
Bob
```

---

## Scenario 8: Deny/Deny

```
Employee --(Deny)--> Department
Department --(Deny)--> Employee
```

**Delete Employee**:

Deleting Bob will cause an exception: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.)`.

**Delete Department**:

If we start over and delete Sales this time, it will cause an exception: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.)`.

---

## Scenario 9: Deny/Cascade

```
Employee --(Deny)--> Department
Department --(Cascade)--> Employee
```

**Delete Employee**:

Deleting Bob will cause an exception: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.)`.

**Delete Department**:

If we start over and delete Sales this time, it will delete all the employees.

```
(empty DB)
```

---

## Conclusion:

Therefore, it seems it is best to use scenario 5 (Nullify/Deny) and you will have to write custom code to delete a department after the last employee is deleted. This scenario will also ensure you don't accidentally delete a department too soon.

Comment: Also set the minimum cardinality for the employees relation of Department to 1. It doesn't replace the need for special code to remove empty departments, but it will catch the error if you fail to do it.